# How to type type

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, pycharm

Pycharm is showing me 2 weird errors regarding this bit of code:

```py
class BaseClass:
    pass


def factory(class_name) -> BaseClass:
    return type(class_name, (BaseClass,), {}) # (1)


class Root(BaseClass):
    pass


def example():
    root = Root()

    Root2 = factory('Root2')
    root2 = Root2()  # (2)
```

The first issue is that `type(class_name, (BaseClass,), {})` has the following issue `Expected type 'BaseClass', got 'type' instead`. How can I type this correctly ?

Secondly, it's probably related to the first issue but nonetheless, I get the error `'BaseClass' object is not callable` for `Root2()`

Any idea on how to resolve this?

### Update

After a pertinent comment from @Tim, I went back and updated my factory to this

```py
def factory(class_name) -> BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return type(class_name, (BaseClass,), {"__init__": __init__})
```

Sadly, it changed nothing. I still get both errors. I noticed this though: if I remove the return type from the factory like this:

```py
def factory(class_name):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return type(class_name, (BaseClass,), {"__init__": __init__})
```

Then, both errors disappear. Why?

Comment: Nowadays `type` returns Type `type` rather than the class type. You didn’t define `__init__` in the 3rd arg for `type` and so it’s not callable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It makes sens. Sadly, I tried but got the same. Check my question for an update.

Comment: Because your return type is not `BaseClass`, you aren't returning an *instance of `BaseClass`*, you are returning an instance of `type`.

Comment: Oh! I see! It makes sense but that never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it actually runs fine. I only got the errors from the linter, but it runs successfully. So I do think it's related to the return type as you surmised. The correct way is to change the return type to `type`

```py
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print('base')


def factory(class_name) -> type:
    def init(self):
        print(class_name)
    return type(class_name, (BaseClass,), {'__init__': init}) # (1)


class Root(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print('root')


def example():
    root = Root()

    Root2 = factory('Root2')
    root2 = Root2()  # (2)
```

This prints

```
root
Root2
```

Comment: With that and the comment from @juanpa.arrivillaga it finally makes sense!